# Vagrant error when running vagrant up

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I am getting the following error when I run `vagrant up`. I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 running on VMware. The host computer is Windows.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu2304:~/DevOps/ansibleintro$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'generic/centos7' version '4.3.2' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "40de0fcd-245c-4f66-8361-c594bffd0689", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```